# Help installing Microsoft office 10 in Ubuntu 14 64 bits using Winetricks

Tags: 14.04, microsoft-office, winetricks

I was trying to install Microsoft Office in Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits using winetricks,I selected wine default prefix,then choose dlls dotnet20 and msxml6 after that a warning message appears (mono not installed, but it was installed previously)

Comment: Hi, for clarity is this Office 2010 (title says "10") ?

Comment: I understand what you did and experienced. What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

The "Mono is not installed" message is normal, just click OK.